# Queue.put.nowait issue in Python 2.7 distributions

Tags: python-2.7, ipython, pyqt4, anaconda

Environment: Windows 10 with with either WinPython or Anaconda Python.

I am debugging python 2.7 code using QT4. The software (MakeHuman) is attempting to install the ipython console as a shell.  This is producing an exception:

```
> Could not load 7_shell Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "./core\mhmain.py", line 541, in loadPlugin
>     module.load(self)   File "plugins/7_shell.py", line 226, in load
>     taskview = category.addTask(ShellTaskView(category))   File "plugins/7_shell.py", line 67, in __init__
>     self.console = self.addTopWidget(ipythonconsole.IPythonConsoleWidget())   File
> "./lib\ipythonconsole.py", line 131, in __init__
>     self.ipyConsole = _QIPythonWidget(customBanner="Welcome to MakeHuman the embedded ipython console\n")   File
> "./lib\ipythonconsole.py", line 80, in __init__
>     kernel_client.start_channels()   File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\MakeHuman\lib\site-packages\qtconsole\kernel_mixins.py",
> line 43, in start_channels
>     super(QtKernelClientMixin, self).start_channels(*args, **kw)   File
> "C:\Anaconda2\envs\MakeHuman\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\inprocess\client.py",
> line 64, in start_channels
>     super(InProcessKernelClient, self).start_channels()   File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\MakeHuman\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\client.py",
> line 102, in start_channels
>     self.kernel_info()   File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\MakeHuman\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\inprocess\client.py",
> line 137, in kernel_info
>     self._dispatch_to_kernel(msg)   File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\MakeHuman\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\inprocess\client.py",
> line 168, in _dispatch_to_kernel
>     self.session.send(stream, msg)   File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\MakeHuman\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\session.py",
> line 684, in send
>     stream.send_multipart(to_send, copy=copy)   File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\MakeHuman\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\inprocess\socket.py",
> line 56, in send_multipart
>     self.queue.put_nowait(msg_parts) AttributeError: 'Queue' object has no attribute 'put_nowait'
```

The problem appears to be internal to the python 2.7 libraries and not related to the MakeHuman code itself.  However, I get the same issue with both WinPython and with Anaconda Python distributions of Python 2.7.

This seems to be the documented standards:

https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/Queue.py#l142
https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.put_nowait

It seems that both WinPython and Anaconda Python are not handling  "Queue.put_nowait"  properly.

Can anyone tell me if this is a real bug in the 2.7 libraries for these distributions, and if so, how I might overcome the problem (properly)?

Here is a link to my thread on the WinPython end:
https://github.com/winpython/winpython/issues/306#issuecomment-201719027

Comment: Could you tweak the code to print out `type(self.queue)` and see what that is and where it's imported from? I wonder if something could have overridden the queue module.